# 16 heures trente ou 16 heures et demie ?

Tags: grammaire, indications-de-temps, nombres

Nous nous sommes posé une question : doit-on donner l'heure (forcément) avec et demie ou avec trente ? À partir de quand dit-on trente et plus demie ?

D'où viens cette règle,  si elle existe ?  ou est-ce simplement une convention ?

Answer (score 10):

Utiliser les quarts ou les demies implique un degré de précision moins grand que d'utiliser un nombre de minutes. « Il est dix heures trente », suivant le contexte, signifie qu'il est entre 10:30 et 10:31, ou au moins qu'il est 10:30 à deux ou trois minutes près. « Il est dix heures et demie » est acceptable sans problème entre 10:20 et 10:40. Les chiffres que je donne ne sont pas des limites précises, juste des ordres de grandeur. La précision peut dépendre du contexte mais il y a toujours une différence perceptible.

Les quarts et les demies ne sont utilisées qu'avec une horloge sur douze heures, probablement parce que ce sont des expressions anciennes (datant d'avant l'accès courant à des horloges qui donnent l'heure à la minute près). Pour 12 heures, on dit plutôt *minuit* ou *midi*. On a donc : *onze heures et demie*, *midi moins le quart*, *midi*, *midi et quart*, *midi et demie*, *une heure moins le quart*, ... On ne dit jamais « *<strike>treize heures moins le quart</strike> » ou « *<strike>seize heures et demie</strike> » (*douze heures et quart* et compagnie sont possibles mais moins courant que *midi/minuit et quart*).

Pour résumer, il est 22h12 (vingt-deux heures douze), ou en moins précis il est dix heures et quart.

Answer (score 5):

Je ne sais pas d'où vient la règle, mais les notions « et quart », « et demie » et « moins le quart » ne sont utilisables que sur les heures comptées sur 12 heures.

Pour les heures comptées sur 24 heures, on doit utiliser « 15 », « 30 » et « 45 », respectivement.

On peut donc dire :

> - dix heures moins le quart (du matin ou du soir)
> - neuf heures quarante-cinq
> - vingt-et-une heures quarante-cinq

mais pas

> vingt-deux heures moins le quart

Comment: Sans oublier que n'importe quelle heure supérieure à 12h peut se lire comme étant l'équivalent d'une heure de moins de 12h (13h30 -> "une heure et demi", "une heure trente" ou "treize heures trente").

Comment: Beaucoup de gens utilisent les heures précises (quinze au lieu de quart, etc) pour lever l'ambiguïté entre le matin et le soir : dans la plupart des cas, "huit heures trente" = 08h30 et "vingt heures trente" = 20h30, mais "huit heures et demie" est ambigu. Tout le monde n'applique pas ce principe, mais c'est suffisamment répandu pour que dire "neuf heures quarante-cinq" pour 21h45 soit un choix risqué.

Answer (score 4):

L'origine du nommage traditionnel des heures, deux périodes de 12 heures avec une précision d'un quart d'heure vient très probablement des premières horloges publiques à cadran qui, à l'instar des cadrans solaires dont elles sont les héritières, ne comportaient qu'une seule aiguille avec au mieux, une graduation tous les quarts d'heures :

[image]
[image]

Photos:
http://visites.aquitaine.fr/cadran-solaire-de-l-eglise-notre-dame
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Detail_of_the_Torre_dell%27Orologio,_Lucca.jpg

L'aiguille des minutes n'a commencé à apparaître qu'à la fin du XVIIe siècle mais des horloges à une aiguille ont continué à être installées jusqu'à la fin du XIXe siècle.

Un clocher était le plus souvent associé à ces horloges et il a commencé par sonner les heures (de 1 à 12 coups) puis s'est mis à sonner aussi chaque quart d'heure (1, 2 et 3 coups).

Une précision plus grande n'était d'une part pas garantie par les mécanismes de l'époque et d'autre part pas nécessaire dans la vie de tous les jours.

Seuls les transports comme la navigation (chronomètres de marine servant à mesurer le méridien) puis surtout l'arrivée des chemins de fer ont rendu nécessaire, d'une part une heure homogène sur un territoire alors qu'auparavant on synchronisait les horloges à midi quand le soleil était au zénith, et d'autre part une précision à la minute, indispensable pour établir les horaires des trains. L'utilisation d'un cycle de 24 heures au lieu de 12 a aussi permis de supprimer l'ambiguïté entre les heures du matin et celles de l'après-midi et du soir. Les heures y sont nommées de manière numérique uniquement, de zéro heure à 23 heures (pas de midi ou minuit), et les minutes y sont aussi nommées de la même façon, de zéro à 59 (pas de quart, demi ou moins le quart).

Alors qu'aujourd'hui, la forme « moins le quart » prévaut, on peut noter qu'elle ne s'est imposée que dans la première moitié du XXe siècle. Auparavant d'autres formes étaient en concurrence dont « moins un quart » et « trois quart » que l'on entend parfois encore aujourd'hui : « Il est midi trois quarts » au lieu de « Il est une heure moins le quart ».

Answer (score 1):

En Europe, le soleil ne passe jamais au zénith, c'est à dire à la verticale. Cela ne se produit qu'entre les tropiques. Il est donc préférable de parler d'apogée.

Comment: L'apogée est le point le plus proche du centre de Terre d'un objet orbitant autour de celle-ci. Or on sait depuis des lustres que le Soleil n'orbite pas autour de la Terre. Par ailleurs, je ne saisi pas le rapport entre la question et cette réponse.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/20464)